# "khaki shorts zipper" vs. "khaki shorts' zipper"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Since you should say "jeans pocket," should you say "khakis shorts zipper"? Or "Khakis shorts' zipper"?

Example sentence:

> He unzipped his khaki shorts(') zipper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would have to be "He unzipped his khaki shorts' zipper," as the shorts are being possessed by him, and the shorts are possessing the zipper.

The idiomatic way of saying this is just "He unzipped his khaki shorts."

"Khaki shorts zipper," would just mean a shorts zipper that is khaki.

Comment: You don't need to say _Unzip the zip(per)_ or _unbutton the buttons_, because the verb has already named the type of fastening.

Answer (score 1):

A khaki shorts zipper is a zipper that is meant to be used as part of khaki shorts. Like “i bought a khaki shorts zipper because the old one was broken”.  The khaki shorts’ zipper is the zipper that is part of the khaki shorts.